# How to add hidden TextArea after checkbox is checked

Tags: php, javascript

I having a trouble to customized one of the generated php where I want to show hidden text field that users can input data once they check the check box.

```
[ ] Data A
[x] Data B  [Text Field Area for User to keyin]
[ ] Data C
```

The checkbox data is fetched from a table as below

```
<tr>
    <td class="ewTableHeader">
      <span>Damaged Item</span>
    </td>
    <td class="ewTableAltRow">
      <span id="cb_x_DamagedItem">
        <?php
          $sSqlWrk = "SELECT `DamegeItemID`, `DamageItemDesc` FROM `acc_damageitem`";

          $rswrk = phpmkr_query($sSqlWrk,$conn) or die("Failed to execute query at line " . __LINE__ . ": " . phpmkr_error($conn) . '<br>SQL:' . $sSqlWrk);

          $x_DamagedItemChk = "";
          $rowcntwrk        = 0;
          $rowswrk          = phpmkr_num_rows($rswrk)-1;

          while ($datawrk = phpmkr_fetch_array($rswrk)) 
          {
            $x_DamagedItemChk .= RenderControl($rowswrk, $rowcntwrk, 1, 1);
            $ar_x_DamagedItem  = explode(",", @$x_DamagedItem);

            $x_DamagedItemChk .= "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"x_DamagedItem[]\" value=\"" . htmlspecialchars(@$datawrk[0]) . "\"";

            foreach ($ar_x_DamagedItem as $cnt_x_DamagedItem) 
            {
              if ($datawrk[0] == trim($cnt_x_DamagedItem)) 
              {
                $x_DamagedItemChk .= " checked";
                break;
              }
            }
            $x_DamagedItemChk .= ">" . $datawrk[1] . RenderControl($rowswrk, $rowcntwrk, 1, 2);

            $rowcntwrk++;
          }
          echo $x_DamagedItemChk;
        ?>
      </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Really appreciate with any advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you either have load it hidden and display on check with js, or load it via ajax on check again with js

Comment: This needs to be done using JavaScript.  Have you tried any JavaScript code to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you can use CSS, you can hide the textarea when the checkbox is not checked.

```
<style>
  input:not(:checked) ~ textarea {
    display: none;
    //or visibility: hidden;
  }
</style>
<input type="checkbox">
Data A
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="checkbox">
Data B
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="checkbox">
Data C
<textarea></textarea>
```

http://jsbin.com/ozucoj/1/